# Error trying to send an email in the background

Tags: android, email

I'm trying to send 2 emails: one with the app and one in the background.  I've used https://github.com/yesidlazaro/GmailBackground for the email in the background.

The button for the email with the app works.  I get a message error sending email when I try the other button &  getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb2bba960.    I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with other button.  I changed this a bit & it still doesn't work & I've shown the errors.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong please?

```
    public class Sad extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button button2;
        Button button3;
        final Context context = this;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_sad);
        }
        public void onClick (View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button2:
                    Intent h = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    h.setType("message/rfc822");
                    h.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"email"});
                    h.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Something bothers me");
                    h.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(h, "Send mail..."));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(Sad.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.button3:

                    BackgroundMail.newBuilder(this)
                    .withUsername("*****@gmail.com")
                    .withPassword("p/w")
                    .withMailto("*********")
                    .withSubject("Something bothers me")
                    .withBody("this is the body")
                    .withOnSuccessCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnSuccessCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //do some magic
                        }
                    })
                    .withOnFailCallback(new BackgroundMail.OnFailCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFail() {
                            //do some magic
                        }
                    })
                    .send();
    }
    ;
}}
```

This bit is really confusing it seems to facilitate 2 different ways to send an email & some of the code is unused.

```
   public class BackgroundMail {
    String TAG = "BackgroundMail";
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String mailto;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private String sendingMessage;
    private String sendingMessageSuccess;
    private String sendingMessageError;
    private boolean processVisibility = true;
    private ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback;
    private OnFailCallback onFailCallback;

    public interface OnSuccessCallback {
        void onSuccess();
    }

    public interface OnFailCallback {
        void onFail();
    }

    public BackgroundMail(Fragment fragment) {
        this(fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    public BackgroundMail(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.sendingMessage = context.getString(R.string.msg_sending_email);
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = context.getString(R.string.msg_email_sent_successfully);
        this.sendingMessageError=context.getString(R.string.msg_error_sending_email);
    }

    private BackgroundMail(Builder builder) {
        mContext = builder.context;
        attachments = builder.attachments;
        username = builder.username;
        password = builder.password;
        mailto = builder.mailto;
        subject = builder.subject;
        body = builder.body;
        setSendingMessage(builder.sendingMessage);
        setSendingMessageSuccess(builder.sendingMessageSuccess);
        setSendingMessageError(builder.sendingMessageError);
        processVisibility = builder.processVisibility;
        setOnSuccessCallback(builder.onSuccessCallback);
        setOnFailCallback(builder.onFailCallback);
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder(Context context) {
        return new Builder(context);
    }

    public static Builder newBuilder(Fragment fragment) {
        return new Builder(fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    public void setGmailUserName(@NonNull String string) {
        this.username = string;
    }

    public void setGmailUserName(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.username = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getGmailUserName() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setGmailPassword(@NonNull String string) {
        this.password = string;
    }

    public void setGmailPassword(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.password = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getGmailPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void showVisibleProgress(boolean state) {
        this.processVisibility = state;
    }

    public boolean isProgressVisible() {
        return processVisibility;
    }

    public void setMailTo(@NonNull String string) {
        this.mailto = string;
    }

    public void setMailTo(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.mailto = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getMailTo() {
        return mailto;
    }

    public void setFormSubject(@NonNull String string) {
        this.subject = string;
    }

    public void setFormSubject(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.subject = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getFormSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setFormBody(@NonNull String string) {
        this.body = string;
    }

    public void setFormBody(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.body = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getFormBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setSendingMessage(@NonNull String string) {
        this.sendingMessage = string;
    }

    public void setSendingMessage(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.sendingMessage = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getSendingMessage() {
        return sendingMessage;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageSuccess(@Nullable String string) {
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = string;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageSuccess(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getSendingMessageSuccess() {
        return sendingMessageSuccess;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageError(@Nullable String string) {
        this.sendingMessageError = string;
    }

    public void setSendingMessageError(@StringRes int strRes) {
        this.sendingMessageError = mContext.getResources().getString(strRes);
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getSendingMessageError() {
        return sendingMessageError;
    }

    public void setOnSuccessCallback(OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback) {
        this.onSuccessCallback = onSuccessCallback;
    }

    public void setOnFailCallback(OnFailCallback onFailCallback) {
        this.onFailCallback = onFailCallback;
    }


    public void send() {
        new SendEmailTask().execute();
    }
public class SendEmailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (processVisibility) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            progressDialog.setMessage(sendingMessage);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            GmailSender sender = new GmailSender(username, password);
            if (!attachments.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
                    if (!attachments.get(i).isEmpty()) {
                        sender.addAttachment(attachments.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            sender.sendMail(subject, body, username, mailto);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (processVisibility) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sendingMessageSuccess)) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, sendingMessageSuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (onSuccessCallback != null) {
                    onSuccessCallback.onSuccess();
                }
            }else {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sendingMessageError)) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, sendingMessageError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if (onFailCallback != null) {
                    onFailCallback.onFail();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static final class Builder {
    private Context context;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String mailto;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    private ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
    private String sendingMessage;
    private String sendingMessageSuccess;
    private String sendingMessageError;
    private boolean processVisibility;
    private OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback;
    private OnFailCallback onFailCallback;

    private Builder(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sendingMessage = context.getString(R.string.msg_sending_email);
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = context.getString(R.string.msg_email_sent_successfully);
        this.sendingMessageError=context.getString(R.string.msg_error_sending_email);
    }

    public Builder withUsername(@NonNull String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withUsername(@StringRes int usernameRes) {
        this.username = context.getResources().getString(usernameRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withPassword(@NonNull String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withPassword(@StringRes int passwordRes) {
        this.password = context.getResources().getString(passwordRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withMailto(@NonNull String mailto) {
        this.mailto = mailto;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withMailto(@StringRes int mailtoRes) {
        this.mailto = context.getResources().getString(mailtoRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSubject(@NonNull String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSubject(@StringRes int subjectRes) {
        this.subject = context.getResources().getString(subjectRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withBody(@NonNull String body) {
        this.body = body;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withBody(@StringRes int bodyRes) {
        this.body = context.getResources().getString(bodyRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withAttachments(@NonNull ArrayList<String> attachments) {
        this.attachments.addAll(attachments);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withAttachments(String...attachments) {
        this.attachments.addAll(Arrays.asList(attachments));
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withAttachments(@ArrayRes int attachmentsRes) {
        this.attachments.addAll(Arrays.asList(context.getResources().getStringArray(attachmentsRes)));
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSendingMessage(@NonNull String sendingMessage) {
        this.sendingMessage = sendingMessage;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSendingMessage(@StringRes int sendingMessageRes) {
        this.sendingMessage = context.getResources().getString(sendingMessageRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSendingMessageSuccess(@Nullable String sendingMessageSuccess) {
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = sendingMessageSuccess;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSendingMessageSuccess(@StringRes int sendingMessageSuccessRes) {
        this.sendingMessageSuccess = context.getResources().getString(sendingMessageSuccessRes);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSendingMessageError(@Nullable String sendingMessageError) {
        this.sendingMessageError = sendingMessageError;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withSendingMessageError(@StringRes int sendingMessageError) {
        this.sendingMessageError = context.getResources().getString(sendingMessageError);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withProcessVisibility(boolean processVisibility) {
        this.processVisibility = processVisibility;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withOnSuccessCallback(OnSuccessCallback onSuccessCallback) {
        this.onSuccessCallback = onSuccessCallback;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder withOnFailCallback(OnFailCallback onFailCallback) {
        this.onFailCallback = onFailCallback;
        return this;
    }

    public BackgroundMail build() {
        return new BackgroundMail(this);
    }

    public BackgroundMail send() {
        BackgroundMail backgroundMail = build();
        backgroundMail.send();
        return backgroundMail;
    }
}
}
```

Gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "queens.feedback"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.7"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

This is the errors in full

```
07-05 02:56:33.782    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
07-05 02:56:33.782    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
07-05 02:56:33.782    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:84)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:233)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:208)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-05 02:56:33.783    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-05 02:56:33.841    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-05 02:56:33.841    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 02:56:33.956    2189-2196/queens.feedback W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 14.286ms
07-05 02:56:34.040    2189-2203/queens.feedback W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-05 02:56:34.040    2189-2203/queens.feedback W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xac335600, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-05 02:56:34.141    2189-2203/queens.feedback E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa392020
07-05 02:56:34.681    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:84)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:233)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:208)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-05 02:56:34.682    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-05 02:56:34.683    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 02:56:35.251    1304-1335/system_process I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
07-05 02:56:35.474    2544-2544/? W/dex2oat﹕ Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-05 02:56:35.475    2544-2544/? W/dex2oat﹕ Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2) for the command line:
07-05 02:56:35.475    2544-2544/? W/dex2oat﹕ /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --compiler-filter=interpret-only --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.apk --oat-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.dex
07-05 02:56:35.475    2544-2544/? I/dex2oat﹕ /system/bin/dex2oat --compiler-filter=interpret-only --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.apk --oat-file=/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_fb/f.dex
07-05 02:56:35.539    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:84)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:233)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at queens.feedback.BackgroundMail$SendEmailTask.doInBackground(BackgroundMail.java:208)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
07-05 02:56:35.540    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-05 02:56:35.569    2544-2544/? I/dex2oat﹕ dex2oat took 94.241ms (threads: 1) arena alloc=0B java alloc=34KB native alloc=674KB free=349KB
07-05 02:56:35.572    2458-2471/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
07-05 02:56:35.589    1591-1591/com.google.android.gms.persistent V/GmsNetworkLocationProvi﹕ DISABLE
07-05 02:56:35.598    1591-1591/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/GCoreNlp﹕ shouldConfirmNlp, NLP off. Ensuring opt-in disabled
07-05 02:56:35.624    2458-2471/com.google.android.gms.unstable D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9c4bd7d0, tid 2471
```

The Gmailsender class

```
public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator
{
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;
    private Multipart _multipart;

    static
    {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GmailSender(String user, String password)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
        _multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception
    {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
        message.setSubject(subject);

        message.setText(body);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if(_multipart.getCount() > 0) {
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(_multipart);
        }
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);

    }

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception
    {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource
    {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type)
        {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data)
        {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType()
        {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException
        {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException
        {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

07-05 02:56:35.539    2189-2480/queens.feedback W/System.err﹕ javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException

It looks like you're failing to authenticate.  If you're positive that this isn't the case, you'll want to catch this error to see if you can get more details from it.  Perhaps GMail isn't letting you use basic authentication, but instead requires secure authentication.

Comment: Thanks I think i seen something like that in the original code but I took it out as i didn't think i needed it.  I've included the GmailSender class.

Comment: Thnere is an option to turn on access to less secure apps in Gmail & it works.  Although it probably isn't best pratice.